# Is it possible to change the delay before the dock appears in OS X on Mac?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I would like to change the delay before the (autohidden) dock appears when I mouse over it.

There is currently a short delay before it appears, and I would like to make it a lot longer (one second instead of 1/10 of a second).

Based on extensive googling, this is a question that many people would like an answer to. I am hoping that the delay is specified somewhere and can be modified.

Many people would like the dock to appear instantly to be able to work more quickly.

Many people would like the dock to appear more slowly in order to effectively hide it.

Can we answer this question definitively?

Comment: You might have some success by switching to [DragThing](http://www.dragthing.com/), a Dock alternative that supports delay and show/hide transition time configuration. Haven't been able to configure it properly (doesn't deactivate the real Dock etc.).

Comment: I did some searching, but I couldn't find any information about how DragThing relates to the regular dock. I wouldn't want to add a new program without being sure that the original dock would be gone. And, while there are programs that get rid of the dock, they seem to cause stability problems since the system needs the dock to function correctly. The impetus for my original question was that modifying the delay would be a non-invasive way to make the dock disappear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a Preference for the delay before the dock appears.

It can be changed in Terminal by typing the following::

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock autohide-delay -float XXX; killall Dock
```

Where XXX is a number of seconds. I set the delay to 10 seconds.

Essentially, I never want to see the Dock, except when I call it up via keyboard with cmd-opt-D.

To reset the dock to the default behavior, type the following in Terminal:

```
defaults delete com.apple.Dock autohide-delay; killall Dock
```

Comment: doesnt work in 10.9 (mavericks) anymore.

Comment: Works perfectly in 11.2.2 ( Big Sur ).

Comment: Works in Ventura as well

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when an app is in fullscreen mode.  I wonder if there's a different setting for that.

Answer (score 3):

Running `defaults read com.apple.dock` and checking [here](http://rixstep.com/2/20060901,00.shtml) revealed no plist setting to change the dock's show delay. [`Secrets.prefpane`](http://secrets.blacktree.com/) and [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) reveal nothing either. Therefore, I'm going to *assume* that there's no way to change the setting.

Comment: This is an incorrect answer because the .plist files do not contain all the settings and you can add new keys to them that macOS will read.

Answer (score 2):

This [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/45315/how-can-i-set-the-os-x-dock-to-show-instantly-instead-of-waiting-half-a-second-in) doesn't answer the question but may be somewhat useful :

> I know it's a little tangential, but I
>   recently stumbled onto an alternate
>   configuration: Set it to **always
>   show, minimum icon size** with
>   **maximum magnification**. It still takes up a little bit of screen space,
>   but I can get to it instantly, and so
>   far I have fewer accidental
>   activations because the small icons
>   take up less surface area on the edge.

Comment: I had read that thread before posting the question, and I agree with the comments there. I don't use the dock at all, but if I did, I would want the icons to stay in the same places at all times. I realize that my question is really similar to that one.

Answer (score 2):

On newer versions of macOS, setting seems to be changed from `autohide-delay` (actual number of seconds) to `autohide-time-modifier` (scaling factor for default delay). So the command becomes:

```bsh
defaults write \
  com.apple.dock \
  autohide-time-modifier \
  -float 0.3

# Dock needs to be restarted
# for change to take effect
killall Dock
```

Obviously, set it to w/ever scale you want instead of `0.3`: say, `0` to remove animation completely.

Comment: Worked for me on Big Sur 11.6, thanks!

Comment: Also worked for me on Monterey / 12.3 where the old method did not (and caused the dock to disappear permanently)

Answer (score 1):

update:

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock autohide -float 1; \
defaults write com.apple.Dock autohide-delay -float 10; \
killall Dock
```

there appear to be two settings (Mojave tested).
autohide (whether to hide it at all) is settable from System Preferences / Dock 
0 = don't hide
1 = autohide

```
defaults read com.apple.Dock | less

{
    autohide = 1;
    "autohide-delay" = 10;
    ...
}
```

@Hans the delay may not have worked for you if the "boolean" was off.

Comment: Working in Big Sur.